# Join Two table result comes as Blank in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

my problem is when i going to join two table altogather i ran into the problem with one table has data another table  has no data but i want to display if data has one table it should display with another table blank . below query i tired but it is getting blank.

```
SELECT seats.busno, seats.seats, busbook.customer,busbook.mobile,seats.date 
FROM seats 
INNER JOIN busbook ON seats.busno=busbook.busno
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want also not matching values you should use left join

```
SELECT seats.busno, seats.seats, busbook.customer,busbook.mobile,seats.date 
FROM seats 
LEFT JOIN busbook ON seats.busno=busbook.busno
```

Answer (score 0):

`INNER` join work only when at least 1 match between the tables.